# Laravel-Inertia-Vue3 project: Internal server error: Codegen node is missing for element/if/for node

Tags: vuejs3, inertiajs, laravel-10

I'm stuck with an error I don't understand. And the solutions I found online didn't work for me, I'm out of options.
I created a project from Laravel bootcamp, followed [Laracasts videos on this subject](https://laracasts.com/series/build-modern-laravel-apps-using-inertia-js), until persistent layout and that's where I failed to make any progress. I watched following videos just in case but it didn't solve my problem.

So, I simplified my code as much as possible to make it still work and reproduce the problem.
First, my app.js file (the relevant part), as instructed by the videos and updated based on vue3 documentation:

```
createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: name => {
        const pages = import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue', {eager: true});
        let page = pages[`./Pages/${name}.vue`];
        page.default.layout ??= AuthenticatedLayout;
        return page;
    },
});
```

As you notice, the AutheticatedLayout is defined as default persistent layout for all pages.

The AuthenticatedLayout.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-900">
<!-- Page Heading -->
            <header class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 shadow" v-if="$slots.header">
                <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                    <slot name="header"/>
                </div>
            </header>

            <!-- Page Content -->
            <main>
                <slot />
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

The view TagList.vue without errors:

```
<template>
    <template>
        TODO TAG LIST title
    </template>
    <p>TAG list</p>
</template>
```

The rendering just displays "TAG list". No title displayed but that's for the demo.

If I change `<template>` to `<template #header>` in order to have the title in the named slot "header", it crashes with the following error:

```
6:49:21 PM [vite] Internal server error: Codegen node is missing for element/if/for node. Apply appropriate transforms first.
  Plugin: vite:vue
  File: /var/www/html/resources/js/Pages/Tag/TagList.vue
      at assert (/var/www/html/node_modules/@vue/compiler-core/dist/compiler-core.cjs.js:496:11)
      at genNode (/var/www/html/node_modules/@vue/compiler-core/dist/compiler-core.cjs.js:2476:7)
[...]
```

I saw that other [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74028448/vite-internal-server-error-codegen-node-is-missing-for-element-if-for-node-app), but it didn't solve my issues.

What did I miss?

Thank you for your time and your help.

Answer (score 0):

I made a workaround. That does not solve nor explain the problem, but in case someone has the same problem, here is my workaround.

Pros: it works!
Cons: you need to add `<main></main>` around the content in every single vue page, which defeats the concept of layout.

**AuthenticatedLayout**: remove the header slot and related code (the whole block).

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-900">
            <!-- Page Content -->
            <slot />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

New component **PageHeader.vue**:

```
<template>
    <header class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 shadow">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-200 leading-tight">
            <slot></slot>
        </h2>
    </div>
    </header>
</template>
```

**TagList.vue**

```
<template>
    <PageHeader>
        TODO TAGLIST translation
    </PageHeader>
    <main>
        <p>TAG list</p>
    </main>
</template>
```